# Could it be a good idea to edit a post with advices and hints to write mathematical posts in english for this site?

Tags: discussion

It is well know the post in this **Meta Math Stack Exchange**, *MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference*. It is useful since is a reference for all users, newbies or no to write and improve their edits in **Mathematics Stack Exchange**.

Also it is a problem for people, as I, that have not good skills and abilities in English language, to write mathematics in English language. Sometimes I copy and paste phrases used in mathematical texts, looking to get a better result. In house I have *TRZECIAK, Writing Mathematical Papers in English*.

If a purpose of this site is to obtain good problems as record files,

> **Question.** Could be a good idea to edit a post with advices and hints to write mathematical posts in English language for this site? I say as analogous previous post like [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Then, like the previous post is a reference TEX for Math Stack Exchange, which I propose in my question, should be useful to improve the posts of people that are not native English speakers. This reference could collect phrases, and some problems of English Grammar.

Comment: Such a post seems extremely broad, and I'm not sure it would be a good fit here. The Mathjax guide is very focused on giving a list of basic syntax, yet there are entire books and courses about basic English grammar and usage (as well as the ELU and ELL stackexchange sites). I think that, in general, the best approach for someone who does not have very good English skills is to post their best translation as well as the original text and tag it as [tag:translation-request].

Comment: Thanks @T.Bongers

Comment: Thanks for your edit **Martin Sleziak.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analogy between models of good English and of attractive $\LaTeX$ is weak if broadly construed.  The MathJax markup that creates mathematical expressions is necessarily hidden and in that sense esoteric.  One hopes that the site is filled with posts that are well-written, and whose English composition is evident.

It is desirable that the English of Questions and Answers be grammatical (and well-spelled), but it strikes me as overly ambitious to attempt a home-grown tutorial on how English can be written well.  There are a couple of SE communities that take up this task ([English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)), using the full features of SE Q&A content rather than as a single meta-post.

So I think the best approach for Math.SE as a Community is to offer suggestions where content is unclear or even to edit for spelling and grammar when the meaning is unambiguous.  I was sorely tempted to edit the OP here, much as I would a post on the main site, but I think it serves as a valuable illustration of how *editing* for English can be as desirable as editing for mathematical expressions.

In that respect the analogy of the two skills seems sound to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @harmath I believe that my idea could be useful.